# Eval for multiple command execution in ksh93, Solaris

Tags: solaris, eval, ksh

I would like to execute two or more commands back to back . But these commands are stored in a variable in my script. For example,

```
var="/usr/bin/ls ; pwd ; pooladm -d; pooladm -e"
```

The problem arises when I execute this variable via my script.
Suppose I go:

```
#!/bin/ksh -p
..
..
var="/usr/bin/ls ; pwd;pooladm -d; pooladm -e"
..
..
$var # DOES NOT WORK ..BUT WORKS WITH EVAL
```

It doesn't work ..
But the moment I use eval :

```
eval $var
```

It works brilliantly.

I was just wondering if there is any other way to execute a bunch of commands stored in a variable without using eval.

**Also** , Is eval usage considered a bad programming practice because my coding standards appear to shun its usage than embrace it . Please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the shell only parses the line once.  So when you expand your $var, it becomes one string containing blanks.  Since you have no executable named '/usr/bin/ls ; pwd;pooladm -d; pooladm -e', it can't run it.

On the other hand, eval takes its arguments are re-scans them, now you get '/usr/bin/ls', 'pwd', and so on.  It works.

`eval` is a little chancy because it leaves a possible security hole -- consider if someone managed to get 'rm -rf /' into the string.  But it's a useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks and echo.  In your case

```
`echo $var`
```

Comment: This isn't ideal. Backquotes are intended for capturing the output of a command for further processing. If the commands in $var write anything to standard output, this solution would capture that output and then throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

You could invoke another copy of the shell to run the command:

```
sh -c "$var"
```

This isn't necessarily better than using eval. The main practical difference is that eval will run the commands in the context of the current shell, while "sh -c" runs the commands in a separate shell instance. If `var` contains commands to set environment variables or change the current directory, you or may not want those commands to affect the current shell.